# Embedding and signing programs in XCode/OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, digital-signature

I have a Mac app developed in XCode that contains a helper executable. When I export the app as a signed application, the helper executable is unable to do things like write to the file system.

I can fix this up in the exported app by using a forced deep codesign from the terminal, but that doesn't help me for distributing the app on the App Store.

There's an "Embedded Binaries" list in the target's general setting. When I add the executable and the library it depends on using the + button in that list, XCode imports the files, but neither automatically adds them to the bundle nor lists them in the "Embedded Binaries" list.

[image: Embedded binaries list]

How do I correctly add this executable to the bundle and have it included and signed for distribution?

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983628/cannot-add-embedded-binaries-other-projects-to-project-dependencies-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

As i remember, it's simple to sign programs in Xcode, the certificate is related to your account.
Some tutorial here [sign](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you Googled answers providing ways to sign code in Xcode?

[Cannot add embedded binaries (other projects) to project dependencies in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983628/cannot-add-embedded-binaries-other-projects-to-project-dependencies-in-xcode)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

I have scanned those links briefly and it seems to me that they explain how to achieve this.

Comment: So the problem is that the program I want to embed is literally just an executable. Not another XCode project, or a library, or anything. I just have the executable.

Comment: Oh I understand. Will let you know if I find a solution